# $p$ the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$ , $x\in G$ an element of order $p$ . Suppose $h\in G$ such that $hxh^{-1}=x^{10} $ . Show that $p=3 $ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group , $p$ the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$ , $x\in G$ an element of order $p$ . Suppose $h\in G$ such that $hxh^{-1}=x^{10} $ . Show that $p=3 $ .

My solution :

let $|G|=d$ .

Claim 1 : $(10, p)=1 $ .

proof : Otherwise $p=2 $or $p=5 $  both of which contradict $hxh^{-1}=x^{10} $ . So $(10,p)=1$ .

claim 2: $(d,p-1)=1 $ .

proof : $(d,p-1)$ is not $1$ then it is divisible by a prime $q$ . So $q\leq p-1<p $ and $q|d $ . Hence contradicting the hypothesis  that $p$ is smallest a prime dividing $d$ .

Back to the main proof :

$x=h^d x h^{-d}= h^{d-1} x^{10} h^{-(d-1)} =..=x^{10^d}$ . So $ x^{10^d-1}=1$ . It gives $10^d=1(\mod p)$ .

By claim 1 and Fermat's theorem $10^{p-1}=1 (\mod p)$

Now by claim 2 we have $s, t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ds+(p-1)t=1 $ .
So $10=10^{ds+(p-1)t}=10^{ds}10^{(p-1)t}=1(\mod p)$ .So $p|9$ .But $p$ is prime . So $p=3 $ .

QED .

Please tell me if i'm missing out some cases or the solution is wrong .

Comment: Why do $p=2$ or $p=5$ contradict $hxh^{-1}=x^{10}$?  It is correct, but not fully justified.

Comment: Also, how do you get $x^{10^d}$?  The first step works, but the following steps no longer have the right form, so you'll need to introduce something in the middle.

Comment: Suppose $p=2 $. Then $x^2=1 $ . So $hxh^{-1}=x^10=\{x^2\}^5=1 $ . Giving $x=1 $ but $x$ is non-indentity as it has order $p$ a prime .

Comment: Yes, that's the justification that's missing for Claim 1.

Comment: $h^{d-1} x^{10} h^{-(d-1)} =h^{d-2}(h x^{10}h^{-1}) h^{-(d-2)} =h^{d-2}(h xh^{-1})^{10} h^{-(d-2)}= h^{d-2}(x^{10})^{10} h^{-(d-2)}= h^{d-2}(x^{10^2}) h^{-(d-2)}=...$ one keeps doing this $d-2 $ more times to reach $x^{10^d}$

Comment: Yes, that's what's missing in Claim 2 (although an induction would be even clearer).

Comment: I see. Thank you . So except this two issues everything is alright , right ?

Comment: It looks OK, but the $p\mid 9$ could use a little justification (if you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is fine, but it can be simplified and streamlined by using the fact that the map $g\mapsto hgh^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $G$.

As a consequence, the element $hxh^{-1}$ has the same order as $x$. On the other hand, the order of $x^{10}$ is $p/{\gcd(10,p)}$, so we have
$$
p=p\gcd(10,p)
$$
Hence $\gcd(10,p)=1$.

Claim 2 is OK.

The final idea is good: in general
$$
h^{k}xh^{-k}=h^{k}h^{-1}x^{10}hh^{-k}=
h^{k-1}x^{10}h^{-k+1}=(h^{k-1}xh^{-k+1})^{10}
$$
(the last step uses the automorphism above) and, by induction,
$$
h^{k}xh^{-k}=(h^{k-n}xh^{-k+n})^{10^n}
$$
In particular, for $k=n=d$,
$$
x=h^dxh^{-d}=x^{10^d}
$$
so $10^d-1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. Finally, as you note, $\gcd(10,p)=1$ implies
$$
10=10^{ds+(p-1)t}\equiv (10^d)^s(10^{p-1})^t\equiv1\pmod{p}
$$
so $p\mid 9$.